# How to find image tags in a string in node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, replace

I have a string with image tags like below

```
 var str = '<img src="www.client.jpg><img src="www.custums.png">';
```

I have to find the image tags and src i.e I need to push the image tags into an array but right now I cannot use jsdom since I had a version problem right now in my server.So, can anyone please suggest me help to do this with not using jsdom.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just split the string and then filter to the urls like so;

```
var str = '<img src="www.client.jpg"><img src="www.custums.png">';

console.log(str.split("\"").filter(t => t.startsWith("www.")));
```

Your example was missing a ", it would make it so this doesn't parse correctly, but assuming the html is actually of that form but without errors it will give you just the urls.

Comment: Hi evanmcdinnal,I may have img tags in between all the kind of tags like div,span etc.As an example I put the above string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use xpath to extract, the path would be `//img@src`. alternatively, you can use an xml to json parser ; sth like [`fast-xml-parser`](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser)

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into an array of image tag. Convert strings into HTML DOM objects as shown below. Then you can easily get the src of image tag.

```js
var str = "<img src='www.client.jpg'><img src='www.custums.png'>";
var newstring = str.replace(/></gi, ">,<"); // Replace '><' with '>,<' so that you can split with ','
var imgs = newstring.split(",");

for(i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
  // Create a temporary div, assign img string as its innerHTML, then gets its content
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.innerHTML = imgs[i];
  // Reassign the imgs array with HTML DOM object instead of string
  imgs[i] = d.firstChild;
  console.log(imgs[i].src);
}
```